# MySQL query not working while using php variable in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL. I am trying to make a simple search form using which I would want to show the results from the database based on the input text entered in the form.
My code is like this:

Form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="GET" id="form">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" >
Age:<input type="text" name="age">
Search<input type="submit" name="submit" id="Search" Value="Search">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Connect.php

```
  <?php
  $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','$user','$password'); 

  if(!$connect){
die('Could not connect'.mysql_error() );  
  }

  $db_selected = mysql_select_db('test');  

  if(!$db_selected){
die('wrong'.mysql_error() );
  }

  ?>
```

Search.php

```
 <?php
  include("includes/connect.php");

  $name=$_GET['name'];


  echo $name;

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE name='\$name'";
  $results= mysql_query($query);


  if (!empty($results)){
echo "query successful" ;
exit;
   }
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
  echo "Age:".$row['age'];
  echo "Name:".$row['name'];
 ?>
```

The `echo $names` ouputs the result correctly and so does `echo "query successful"`.
However the

```
echo "Age:".$row['age']; 
echo "Name:".$row['name'];
```

only echo's the string part and the query does not seem to fetch any results.

I tried changing the `mysql_fetch_asso`c to `mysql_fetch_array`, but it does not do anything either. Could anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here. My DB table has two columns and two rows.

Comment: why are you escaping `$name` !!

Comment: Also, mysql functions are now deprecated and it's time to move on to PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're escaping the `$` in the variable by doing `\$`.
Try:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE name='$name'";
```

**EDIT**

From the discussion below.

The problem with the `undefined index` is the fact that you are using `$row['age']` when really, the column name in the database is `Age`. Therefore you must use `$row['Age']` when referring to the item. The same goes for `name`.

Comment: Thanks.I tried the query suggested by you. It now gives me "Notice: Undefined index: name and Notice: Undefined index: age " error msg. But if I add qoutes around name ($query = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE 'name'='$name'";) the error goes away but still the query does not fetch any results.

Comment: do you have columns named `age` and `name` in `cats`? The quotes are to surround the value and NOT the column name.

Comment: Yes, I have a column named age in my table cats.

Comment: It gives me " resource(5) of type (mysql result) ".No idea what that means.

Comment: then try `var_dump($row);`. `mysql_query` returns a MySQL resource which you are getting.

Comment: var_dump($row); gave me-  Age:Name:bool(false)

Comment: the `bool(false)` I'm assuming is from the dump. This means you have an error with your query still.

Comment: Unable to figure out what should i change to make it work.

$query = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE 'name'='$name'";
$results= mysql_query($query); 

 $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
 echo "Age:".$row['age'];
 echo "Name:".$row['name'];

 var_dump($row);

Comment: get rid of the single quotes in `WHERE 'name'=`. That is a MySQL syntax error

Comment: I am getting these following msges by removing the single quotes from 'name'= ,
Notice: Undefined index: age in ..\search.php 
Age:
Notice: Undefined index: name in ..\search.php 
Name: But the var_dump($row);now gives me: array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "Mishka" ["Age"]=> string(1) "8" }

Comment: comment out the two echo's and post the dump

Comment: Commenting the two echo's the dump gives me this- array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "Mishka" ["Age"]=> string(1) "8" }

Comment: I guess i figured it out. The column names had the first alphabets in caps which I failed to do in the two echo's. I changed it and worked.:)

Comment: Thanks a lot UnholyRanger for your help and time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No Problem. Just remember to show your appreciation with an up vote and acceptance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE name='" . $name . "'";
```

or without concatenation

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE name='$name'";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

$query = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE name = '$name'";

Also, when you call "exit;" in the following block it will cancel the execution of the rest of your script:

```
    if (!empty($results)){
     echo "query successful" ;
     exit;
    }
```